# Injected javascript does not execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a piece of javascript that integrates a webpage with an external system. Currently, what I have is a very small amount of code that dynamically inserts a script element into the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://example.com/example.php?arg1=1&arg2=2";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```

The JS returned by the external system is a large one-line document.write call which writes a table to the page.

```
document.write('<table><tr><td>blah</td></tr></table>');
```

When I inject this script element into the page, I can see it using a DOM inspector, but the script does not appear to execute. If I put the script element into the HTML manually, the javascript executes just fine (so it's not a same origin policy or malformed html error...), but I'd like it to be dynamic.

Any ideas why the javascript isn't executing?

Comment: Test to see if the script is running, by inserting a `alert("it is running")`.

Comment: Do you make an eval() after inserting your script ?

Comment: If you use Chrome developer tools (or any other appropriate tools), do you see the GET request for the script in the network tab?

Comment: @FelixKling I can see the get request go out, yes. I can even see an "Evaluate Script" row in the timeline for it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `document.write` after the DOM is ready will replace the contents of the page with whatever it is you're writing.

I suggest using one of the actual DOM manipulation methods if you want to insert anything into a page.

As far as the script not executing, are you positive it's being attached correctly?  Have you tried setting a javascript breakpoint on the included script to verify that this is the case?

Comment: *"If I put the script element into the HTML manually, the javascript executes just fine"*.

Comment: Reading comprehension before coffee is severely lacking apparently.

Comment: Yes because then it will be rendered when that element is parsed, but if he uses document.write() when the DOM has been loaded it will replace the current DOM.

Comment: I currently have no control over the JS returned by the external system. Let's get it running first, and then deal with getting it running correctly. :)

Comment: @danbo have you tried the debugger?  (Also, if you don't want it to replace the current contents AND you can't change it, don't attach the script on the ready event.)

Comment: @tkone I can put a breakpoint on the returned one-liner and it gets hit. So it is executing - is there some change in Javascript context between injecting it dynamically and having it statically on the page?

Comment: @danbo: you really should just have tried a dummy `alert("yes, i am executed")` script first! What exactly is the dynamically loaded script doing?

Comment: @Frunsi The dynamically loaded script is a large one-liner document.write() that puts a table on the page. I just tried directing it to a dummy script like suggesting it, and that runs - I suppose my real question now is, is the document variable that script sees the correct one?

Comment: @danbo what is the doctype of your page?  XHTML by any chance?  XHTML disallows `document.write` (and you can too!)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Because you are just including it, not executing.</strike> As you are using jQuery, take a look in the `$.getScript()` function.

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/
```

It will fit your needs. This function is an Ajax function, so take care, because its behavior is asynchronous. Use its callbacks to execute code that is based in the loaded script.

**Edit:** Felix corrected me about the script execution, but I still think that you may give the function a try.

Comment: Normally scripts get executed automatically once they are loaded.

Comment: I think he means that the script might have an included function and that function isn't invoked.  But yes, if it's just commands it'll execute immediately after being attached.

Comment: getScript doesn't work either. When I insert the script element into the HTML, aren't I just including it then too?

Comment: @danbo: I said that based in the documentation description of the `$.getScript()` function. Take a look: `Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code (it the same use by google for analytics or facebook).

Put it on the bottom of your page ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var script = document.createElement('script'); 
            script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
            script.async = true;
        script.src = '/example.php?arg1=1&arg2=2';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
    })();
</script>
```

OR as [davidbuzatto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469201/davidbuzatto) suggest, you have to use $.getScript() which is a shorthand $.ajax() function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("/example.php?arg1=1&arg2=2", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log(data); //data returned
        console.log(textStatus); //success
        console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
        console.log('Load was performed.');
   });
});
```

**Edit :**
Seens you have probably a cross-domain restriction, just try to use relative url "/example.php?arg1=1&arg2=2" instead of the full url for the include.
Or if it's not the same web server, use a cross-domain.xml file.

Comment: Tried both, neither works. For the getScript(), I get a "success" for textStatus, 200 for jqxhr.status, but "data" is undefined.

Comment: Ok so, you have probably a cross-domain restriction, just try to use relative url "/example.php?arg1=1&arg2=2" instead of the full url

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use JSONP to achieve that and using a call back function to append it to body tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://example.com/example.php?arg1=1&arg2=2&callback=showit(data)";
document.body.appendChild(script);
});

 function showit(data){document.write(data);}
```

Comment: *"When I inject this script element into the page, I can see it using a DOM inspector, but the script does not appear to execute."*

Comment: I think you need to write it on the document. it is in cache but not written in document

Comment: That means the content of the script is something like `showit('html here');`. It's not going to be different than having `document.write('html here')` directly inside the script.

Comment: yeah you are right. but i think the problem is with script type which is javascript confusing browser to load it as html

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stick the JS in a separate window/iframe where it executes and displays the tables correctly, and then pull that table using AJAX to that page?

JQuery AJAX is the easiest to use IMO:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I don't know if I understand you. Will the JavaScript run on the html I get back from an AJAX request?

Comment: The idea is that the javascript will execute on the other page and display that table, but that page never actually shows, but instead passes the HTML through AJAX to your page where you can display it.

Answer (score 0):

I've always seen this done more like:

```
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt>---scripthere---' + '</scr' + 'ipt>');
```

I'm assuming it is for similar reasons. Try that instead of creating a "real" script element.